# Apache issue connecting to port 8080

Tags: apache

I have setup my apache conf file, as per instructions here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7

I am running RHEL 7.

I added:

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

My sites-enabled folder has a fusio.conf file as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName server.company.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/fusio/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/fusio/public>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

        # rewrite
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/$1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
        RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
    </Directory>

    # log
    LogLevel warn
    # ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/fusio.error.log
    # CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/fusio.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
~
```

However when I connect to server.mycompany.net:8080, I do not get a response.  This site can’t be reached

I can connect directly to server.mycompany.net and see the files in the fusio folder, but what am I missing?

I have added Listed 8080 to the conf file.

Comment: Can we assume `Listed 8080` is actually `Listen 8080`?  Put your LogLevel to debug in both your generic configuration, and that new VirtualHost and try again.  You have to have some logs somewhere.  If it does not connect at all, is port 8080 in LISTEN?  Do you have a firewall blocking it?  Or SELinux?  And do not comment your log files, separating them from the generic Apache log files is the way to go.  Oh and restart your Apache after config. change.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have opened the port on your firewall (probably `iptables` or `firewalld`).

From the server itself, perform the following:

```
$ curl --header "Host: server.company.net" http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

If you get a response, that means apache is running, but your firewall to the internet is not letting it through on port 8080.

---

### firewalld

Check to see if you are running `firewalld`

```
# firewall-cmd --state
```

If the response is `running`, let's add it

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

---

### iptables

Check to see if you are using `iptables` (iptables are kernel modifications, so there is no "service" that is running.  if rules are showing, they are enabled.)

```
# iptables -L
```

If you see rules, then lets add another.

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Check /etc/apache2/ports.conf. You need to specify ports there.

Listen 80
Listen 8080
......